# Angular 4 style parent and router-outlet

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

Let's assume we have this code:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to give a color background to `<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">` when the component fetched by the router-outlet is myComponent. The purpose of that is that I want the background color takes all the width of the column.

Someone has a trick?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this job with:

```
[style.background-color]="getBackgroundColor()"
```

in your component.ts:

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((route: any) => this.route= route);
}
getBackgroundColor() {
    if (this.url) {
        if (this.route.url === '/yourRoute'{
        return 'white'
        } else {
        return '#6772e5'
        }
    } else {
        return '#6772e5'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this. If you want the parent to change style when a certain child component is active, it would take a bit of coding to work it out.

### Method 1: Shared Service

You need to create a shared service which controls a state that the parent component subscribes to. The method "emitChange" will change the state "fillColorSubject", which returns as an observable "fillColor" to subscribe to.

**fill-color-service.ts**:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()

export class FillColorService {
    private fillColorSubject = new Subject<boolean>();
    fillColor = this.fillColorSubject.asObservable();
    emitChange(fill : boolean) {
        this.fillColorSubject.next(fill);
    }
}
```

The child component will emit a change to the service when it's initialized and when it's destroyed.

**my.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { FillColorService } from 'fill-color-service';

@Component( {
  templateUrl: 'my.component.html'
} )

export class myComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor ( private _fillColorService: FillColorService ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._fillColorService.emitChange(true);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._fillColorService.emitChange(false);
  }
}
```

Now the parent component will need to subscribe to the service. When the state changes, a switch (fillColumn) will changes the column state.

**parent.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FillColorService } from 'fill-color-service';

@Component( {
  templateUrl: 'parent.component.html'
} )

export class parentComponent {
  fillColumn : boolean;

  constructor ( private _fillColorService: FillColorService ) {
    _fillColorService.fillColor .subscribe(
      fill => {
        this.fillColumn = fill;
      });
  }
}
```

Your template needs to be able to reflect the change with a conditional class.

**parent.component.html**:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9" [ngClass]="{ 'fill': fillColumn }">
            <app-component></app-component>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Method 2: Emitting Event from Child

This method will not work with  as it does not allow binding. You need to define your own selector for this. This method has the same idea as the shared service except through direct event binding.

First, the parent has a method (fillColor) that can be triggered to change the switch (fillColumn).

**parent.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component( {
  templateUrl: 'parent.component.html'
} )

export class parentComponent {
  fillColumn : boolean;

  fillColor( fill : boolean = false ) {
    this.fillColumn = fill;
  }
}
```

Then, the child myComponent needs to emit an event (fillParentColor) with a boolean value to trigger the parent change.

**my.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component( {
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: 'my.component.html'
} )

export class myComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Output() fillParentColor = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fillParentColor.emit(true);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.fillParentColor.emit(false);
  }
}
```

Finally, your template will need to be able to trigger the parent component event when child event is emitted. When myComponent's "fillParentColor" event is triggered, parentComponent's "fillColor" event will be fired with a boolean parameter. You also need to put a conditional class (fill) to your column based on your "fillColumn" switch.

**parent.component.html**:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9" [ngClass]="{ 'fill': fillColumn }">
            <app-component (fillParentColor)="fillColor($event)"></app-component>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer Use:

:host { background: cornflowerblue; }
as the css for the hosted component, to change background of the router outlet.

Long Answer: Angular CSS pseudo selector/modifier You can affect the hosting component with the :host modifier. In the case that you would like to change the router oulet styling, add css to the component that will be hosted.

NOTE: The use of an Angular CSS pseudo selector/modifier - is quite different to a function targeting the style attribute. It has re-use benefits as it should work regardless of host AND minimizes functions in the template.

Comment: Ok - Now I understand. Not duplicate within the answers to this question, but duplicate in that I used this answer for 2x questions. My answer was applicable in both cases - how then should I achieve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70281293/how-to-add-css-to-router-outlet-element